# magento CE 1.9.2 color swatches

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am using magento C.E. 1.9.2 built in color swatch functionality.

I have enable color and size swatch from backend and I have configure one product.

When I go to detail page its show drop-down option instead of swatches.

Here are the links:

1. [category Page](http://www.flatcomfort.com/bedding/sets/venice-sets.html)
2. [Product details page of Configurable product](http://www.flatcomfort.com/bedding/sets/venice-sets/percale-venice-set.html)

Comment: Show us what you have done so far

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!